# geometry not found in axis

Tags: pandas, geopandas, shapely

I have two Geopandas dataframes. the schema looks like below.

```
inventoryid                 object
dsuid                       object
basinquantum                object
reservoir                   object
geometry                  geometry
crs_epsg                    object
buffer_dist                float64
buffer                    geometry
```

The second dataframe schema looks like this

```
API12              object
geometry         geometry
Basin              object
```

since first dataframe having two geometry types am setting geometry to buffer  column

```
wells1=wells1.set_geometry("buffer")
```

I am performing intersection operation

```
res_intersection = gpd.overlay(wells2,wells1,how='intersection')
```

Although geometry column is present but still i am getting error like
"['geometry'] not found in axis"

Answer (score 0):

- creating a repeatable section of code that matches your description
- this does fail in my environment with a different error when using **pygeos** `GEOSException: IllegalArgumentException: Argument must be Polygonal or LinearRing`

  - will further work on this and if necessary raise BUG against **geopandas**
  - will try against main branch not just v0.11 and investigate other versions of **pygeos** and **geos**
- this does work with **rtree**

```
import geopandas as gpd

pygeos = False
gpd._compat.set_use_pygeos(pygeos)

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
cities = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_cities"))

# construct geodataframes logically equivalent to question
# two geometry columns
wells1 = cities.iloc[[11, 36, 50, 113, 158, 161, 172, 199]].copy()
wells1["buffer"] = (
    wells1.to_crs(wells1.estimate_utm_crs()).buffer(1.5 * 10**5).to_crs(wells1.crs)
)
wells1 = wells1.set_geometry("buffer")
wells2 = world.iloc[[43, 54, 55, 58, 82, 129, 130]].copy()

gdf_i = gpd.overlay(wells2, wells1, how="intersection")

gdf_i.explore(height=300, width=500)
```

#### output

[image]

#### Environment

```
gpd.get_versions()
```

### SYSTEM INFO

python     : 3.10.6 (main, Aug 30 2022, 05:11:14) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)]
machine    : macOS-11.6.8-x86_64-i386-64bit

### GEOS, GDAL, PROJ INFO

GEOS       : 3.11.0
GEOS lib   : /usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.11.0/lib/libgeos_c.dylib
GDAL       : 3.4.1
PROJ       : 9.1.0

### PYTHON DEPENDENCIES

geopandas  : 0.11.1
numpy      : 1.23.3
pandas     : 1.4.4
pyproj     : 3.4.0
shapely    : 1.8.4
fiona      : 1.8.21
geoalchemy2: None
geopy      : None
matplotlib : 3.5.3
mapclassify: 2.4.3
pygeos     : 0.13
pyogrio    : None
psycopg2   : None
pyarrow    : None
rtree      : 1.0.0